# Convert Apache Log Datetime Format Using Command Line

Tags: linux, apache, datetime

I have a line like this to extract the datetime per hour of a apache log

```
awk '{print $4}' elasticsearch.log.* | cut -c2-15 | sed -e 's/$/:00:00/
```

The problem is that the output date is formatted like below

```
07/Jul/2014:06:00:00
```

Is there a way to convert the datetime format on the fly using command line to a more common format like 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' e.g. 2014-07-07 06:00:00 ?

One way I found right now is using an intermediary script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re


months = {'Jan': '01', 'Feb': '02', 'Mar': '03', 'Apr': '04', 'May': '05', 'Jun': '06', 'Jul': '07', 'Aug': '08', 'Sep': '09', 'Oct': '10', 'Nov': '11', 'Dec' : '12'}
regex = re.compile("(\d{2})/(\w+)/(\d{4}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})",re.IGNORECASE)
for line in sys.stdin:
    try:
        r = regex.search(line)
        g = r.groups()
        print g[2] + '-' + months[g[1]] + '-' + g[0] + ' ' + g[3] + ':' + g[4] + ':' + g[5]
    except:
        pass
```

but i'm looking if there is a much shorter way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps `date` (of GNU coreutils at least) can be of help here. It can recognize many different date formats, but in your case the slashes have to be `tr`anslated into spaces first.

```
$ echo '07/Jul/2014 06:00:00\n09/Aug/2015 07:01:02' |
> tr '/' ' ' | date -f - +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S
2014-07-07 06:00:00
2015-08-09 07:01:02
```

Oops, I assumed that the first colon in your example was a typo and should have been a space. Your regex shows that I was wrong. In that case you could do:

```
$ echo '07/Jul/2014:06:00:00\n09/Aug/2015:07:01:02' |
> sed -e 's/\// /g;s/:/ /1' | date -f - +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S
2014-07-07 06:00:00
2015-08-09 07:01:02
```

Hope this helps.